# Is there an online Esperanto word stem "diagrammer?"

Tags: computational-linguistics, morphemes, esperanto, morphological-analysis

I'm wondering if there is a site or resource that will take an Esperanto word and diagram the different components. For example, given "malsanulejo," the "diagrammer" would return something like:

mal-: prefix meaning "opposite"
-san-: root meaning "healthy"
-ul: suffix meaning "human"
-ej: suffix meaning place
-o: suffix forming a noun

Comment: You might want to pose this question to the Esperanto Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

Saying it linguistically, you are looking for a tool that does morphological analysis for Esperanto. There is a great variety of such tools around and I remember that some of them were also trained and tested for Esperanto, but alas, I don't have the details (how the tool was named and whether it is available under a free licence) ready

A quick search for "Esperanto morphological tool" brought up a reference to [Theresa Guinnard's Esperanto Word Segmenter](https://github.com/tguinard/EsperantoWordSegmenter) on GitHub, I am sure there are more tools outside.